# Organizational membership

Tags: civimember, relationships

Using 4.7.x.  I am trying to create a membership type where an Organization is the member.  How do I do that?  I see some references from a few years ago on the forum about selecting what contact type it's for, but I don't see that option for that in creating a membership type.

Obviously, a real person (contact) is going to do the actual signing up.  Hopefully that person and other employees of the organization will inherit membership privileges.

Is all of this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your Membership Type as you would expect to. Use 'inherited relationships' if you want eg Employees of that organisation to be considered members.

Then on the Contribution page, use the 'on behalf of organisation' settings on the first screen to set up so Person A can sign up on Behalf of Org B.

Check out the documentation link below. Won't be hard to find once you know to search for 'on behalf of' phrase

NOTE: a contact needs to have a Permissioned and Current 'Employee of' relationship if they are to have the Org field prefilled eg when renewing via a checksum

[Documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/online-membership-sign-up/#organisational-memberships)

Comment: Thanks Pete!  How do I set it up so that the organization in question is based on an existing relationship of the contact?  In this instance, the Media contact for an organization (a relationship) is the designated contact for the organizations that will be members.  All media contacts and organizations are already in the database with relationships set.

Comment: If i get you right, just ensure your Media contacts has a Permissioned 'current employee of' relationship to their Org.